# .htaccess set up issue

Tags: .htaccess, xampp

I have a folder in my `htdocs` folder `ChemLabDB` and inside the directory I have my HTML files that the user can browser from their browsers. When the user put the path to the directory, the browser displays all the files. I put the `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` file in the directory. Now everytime I visit the website, I get a enter password prompt.

My Directory:
[image]

My `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Not Available to Users"
AuthUserfile "../htdocs/ChemLabDB/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

What do I modify so the user can browse without having to enter authentication credentials. The only time a user is REQUIRED (for security) to enter is when they try to browse the directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to take refuge of `Basic Authentication`. Just put this line in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
```

And don't forget to comment out `Basic Authentication` code.

Comment: Check your Apache error log and pls tell me what the error is.

Comment: I restarted the server and will post the logcat if it still causes issues. Thanks

Comment: When you say `root` what do you mean>?

Comment: By root I means DOCUENT_ROOT. If you can check your Apache error.log it will be great to debug it.

Comment: My MYSQL server is having issue starting up it seems. Also, I deleted the `htaccess` file entirely and it's not working which means I have to fix the server first.

Comment: Yes I believe htdocs should be your DOCUMENT_ROOT. (Please make sure you have `Options All` and `AllowOverride All` in your Apache config.

Comment: I have the following `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI`. Is that okay?

Comment: You need to have `Options -Indexes` either in Apache config or `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` after that long `Options` line

Comment: I updated my question to show what the user see when they navigate to the folder inside the `HTDOCS` directory. I want to prevent that and instead take the user to another page.

Comment: Can you add `Options -Indexes` line in `htdocs/ChemLabDB/.htaccess` and test?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38737/discussion-between-sikni8-and-anubhava)

Comment: just replace Options line by: `Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI` (remove Indexes)